# Opening and closing of indices using Curator in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I have a few indices with prefix "log-2014" and I need to close these indices. I would prefer to do it with the Curator tool, rather than the API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
curator --host localhost --port 9200  close indices --prefix log-2014
```

Assuming the elasticsearch is running on locahost at port 9200.